# Postgresql - XML to string conversion issue

Tags: xml, postgresql

Here is my query:

```
select XMLSERIALIZE(query_to_xml('select * from foo order by field1, field2 offset 1 limit 2', true, false,'') as character varying)
```

I receive this error:

```
ERREUR:  erreur de syntaxe sur ou près de « query_to_xml »
LINE 1: select XMLSERIALIZE(query_to_xml('select * from foo ord...
                        ^

********** Erreur **********

ERREUR: erreur de syntaxe sur ou près de « query_to_xml »
État SQL :42601
Caractère : 21
```

Translation from french to english :
`erreur de syntaxe sur ou près de(...)` is equivalent to `syntax error near(...)`

What am I doing wrong ?

**EDIT:**
I tried those two syntaxes too with no luck :

> select XMLSERIALIZE(DOCUMENT query_to_xml('select * from foo ord
>   select XMLSERIALIZE(CONTENT query_to_xml('select * from foo ord

**Postgresql 8.3**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here how I solve my problem. I failed to indicate the casting type.

Either syntaxes work:

> select XMLSERIALIZE(DOCUMENT query_to_xml('select * from foo order by 1', false, false,'') as **text**)
>
> select XMLSERIALIZE(DOCUMENT query_to_xml('select * from foo order by 1', false, false,'') as **varchar**)

Nota: I could replace DOCUMENT with CONTENT and it works like a charm.

Comment: Then my suggestion was not wrong. You indeed needed the `document/content` words.

Comment: @Clodoaldo Sure but your suggestion at first was just a cut/paste of Postgresql doc and not a specific answer to my initial problem. BTW your suggestion help me **greatly** for finding what's was wrong in my query. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

```
select XMLSERIALIZE({ DOCUMENT | CONTENT } query_to_xml(
```